# Perl regex \d+ and [0-9] operators show only single digit in a alpha-numeric string

Tags: regex, linux, string, perl

I encountered the following problem: If I use the code in the first example the variable `$1` includes only the last digit of each string. However, if I use the third example where each "string" is just a number the `$1` variable shows the full number with all digits. To me it appears that the `\d+` operator works differently in alpha-numeric context and just numeric context.

Here are my questions: Can you reproduce this? Is this behavior intended? How can I capture the full number in the alpha-numeric context using a regex operation in perl? If the nature of the `\d` operator is by nature lazy, can I make it more greedy (if true, how would i do it?)?

Example 1:

```
perl -e 'for ($i = 199; $i < 201; $i ++) { print "words".$i."words\n"}' | perl -ne 'if (/\A\w+(\d+)\w+/) {$num = $1; print $num,"\n";}'
```

Output:

```
9
0
```

Example 2:

```
perl -e 'for ($i = 199; $i < 201; $i ++) { print "words".$i."words\n"}' | perl -ne 'if (/\A\w+([0-9]+)\w+/) {$num = $1; print $num,"\n";}'
```

Output:

```
9
0
```

Example 3:

```
perl -e 'for ($i = 199; $i < 201; $i ++) { print "words".$i."words\n"}' | perl -ne 'if (/(\d+)/) {$num = $1; print $num,"\n";}'
```

Output:

```
199
200
```

Thanks in advance. Any help is highly appreciated.

Best,
Chris

Comment: `\w` matches digits, and `\w+` is greedy

Comment: @aschepler : Ok, I did not think about the possibility that "word" characters are also digits.

Comment: Tip: `/...\w+/`  can be simplified to `/...\w/` (unless you use `$&`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The results you get are expected. In `/\A\w+(\d+)\w+/`, the first `\w+` is a greedy pattern and will grab as many chars as it can match, and since `\w` also matches digits.

Either use lazy quantifier - [`/\A\w+?(\d+)\w+/`](https://regex101.com/r/gzLYEm/1/), or subtract the digit from `\w` (e.g. like in [`/\A[^\W\d]+(\d+)\w+/`](https://regex101.com/r/gzLYEm/2)). The `\w+?` will match 1 or more word chars (letters/digits/`_`) *as few as possible*, and `[^\W\d]` matches any letters or `_` symbols, thus, no need to use a lazy quantifier with this pattern.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that digits are matched by \w.

You should replace "\w" with "\D" ("not digit").
For example :

```
perl -e 'for ($i = 199; $i < 201; $i ++) { print "words".$i."words\n"}' | perl -ne 'if (/\A\D+(\d+)\D+/) {$num = $1; print $num,"\n";}'
```

Output:

```
199
200
```

Of course, if your data can contain more than one occurrence of digits in a single string, you'll need some more precise regexp.